# What is the difference between an independent and an unlabelled candidate?

Tags: election, united-kingdom

According to the [official results of the Richmond-Park by-election, 2016](https://cabnet.richmond.gov.uk/mgElectionAreaResults.aspx?ID=81&RPID=503020385), Goldsmith and Syms are *Independent* whereas Powell is not labelled at all.  My assumption was that anybody who is not registered on behalf of a recognised political party would be labelled as *Independent*.  What determines the difference between independent and having no label at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stand as a candidate in the UK parliamentary election or by-election as an independent candidate and you want the word *independent* to appear on the ballot paper, you are required to state this on the nomination form. If you leave this part of the form **blank**, your name will appear as *unlabelled* (without anything).

> 1.8 The following is optional:
>
> A description – if you want the word ‘Independent’, and/or
> ‘Annibynnol’ in Wales, to appear on the ballot paper
> underneath your name, you need to state this on the
> nomination form. No other descriptions are allowed for
> candidates who are not standing on behalf of a registered political party. Alternatively, **you may choose not to have
> a description at all by leaving this part of the form blank**.

(emphasis mine)

[UK Parliamentary general
election: [Guidance for candidates and agents](http://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/173018/UKPGE-Part-2a-Standing-as-an-independent-candidate.pdf)]